# Windows XP Remote Desktop Connection with multiple monitors

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I know you can use `mstsc /multimon` to have multiple monitor support when connecting to a Windows 7 or [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 machine, but is there a way to have that support when connecting to a Windows XP machine?

We currently moved from physically having our computers to having to remote into them, and I had three monitors, and I'm only using one at the moment. I would really like to be able to use the three monitors and individual monitors again. I know you can use `/span` and have it work across all three if they're the same height, etc., but that's not what I'm looking for.

Alternatively if multimonitor option truly won't work on a Windows XP machine then is there a way to use `/span` and still get the multiple monitor functionality? A program that does that or something?

Comment: I would just point out for anybody reading this that /multimon only works properly on Windows 7 if the machine you're remoting into is running Ultimate or Enterprise; otherwise you're limited to /span functionality.  (I don't believe Server 2008 has any limitations depending on SKU.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SplitView](http://www.splitview.com/) is probably the only tool that will be able to help in conjunction with `/span`.  The `/multimon` switch only works with Win 7/2008 R2.

Comment: I was checking splitview out before and I'm currently getting a colleague to test it out. Any idea if it works with more then 2 monitors?

Comment: I've never actually used it, so I can't tell you.  My gut says it should support as many monitors as the host system has, but one never knows.  I can't seem to find a link to documentation on their site, so you might just have to download the trial and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `mstsc /span` instead of `/multimon`. As far as I remember, this is the old option we used back then. Alternatives includes use of AMD display cards and eyefinity options.